# Is it possible to generate references to a JButton from coordinates?

Tags: java, swing

A game I'm creating uses a grid of JButtons as the UI,

```
public static JButton b11 = new JButton(".");
public static JButton b21 = new JButton(".");
```

Where b11 and b21 are the buttons representing (1,1) and (2,1), respectively.  I'm using the ActionListener system to process runtime events, and was wondering if there's a way to reference one of these buttons using just the coordinates. (I.E., if the game says to deal 10 damage to the unit at (1,1), how can I reference b11 from just the coordinates?)

Comment: Why do you not use an array for holding the references to the `JButton` instances?

Comment: Progman is correct, a 2 dimensional array of JButton would be better. Then you could directly find the button.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways in order to achieve that. First there is the solution where you create a `HashMap<Point,JButton>` and holding each button with its coordinate. So when user inputs `2,3` for example, you just `hashmap.get(new Point(2,3));` and it gives you the `JButton`. An example to fully illustrate what I mean:

```
public class PointButtonTest extends JFrame {
    private HashMap<Point, JToggleButton> buttons;

    public PointButtonTest() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buttons = new HashMap<>();
        createButtons();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        String xString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give the X of the coordinate:");
        String yString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give the Y of the coordinate:");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(xString) - 1;
        int y = Integer.parseInt(yString) - 1;
        JToggleButton button = buttons.get(new Point(x, y));
        button.setSelected(true);
    }

    private void createButtons() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton((i + 1) + "," + (j + 1)); //more human
                Point p = new Point(i, j);
                buttons.put(p, button);
                add(button);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new PointButtonTest().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Where user is asked to give `X` and `Y` and the button with these coordinates gets selected. Run it and you will see.

Another way, is to create a new `JButton` class, where there is a field named `coordinates` (or something). Then you keep all the buttons into a simpler structure (maybe an `ArrayList<PointButton>`) and you just iterate through it in order to find the one with these coords.

Something like:

```
private static class PointButton extends JButton {
    private Point coordinates;

    public PointButton(Point coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public PointButton(int x, int y) {
        this.coordinates = new Point(x, y);
    }

    public Point getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }
}
```